# How I can receive URL from browser in Android?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I want to perform OAuth2 authorization process through a standard browser.
Like this:

```
static public class Helper extends Activity {

    private static final int OAUTH2_CODE = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("my url");
        startActivityForResult(intent, OAUTH2_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == OAUTH2_CODE) {
            accessToken = getAccessToken(data); // method to get access token
        }
    }
}
```

When the method `startActivityForResult` is called the browser is started and authorization is carried out. After this the method `onActivityResult` is invoked, but I receive `null` in method `onActivityResult` instead of some data.

I use `intent-filer` in `AndroidManifest.xml` for processing browser redirect in the success case, but I'd like to use `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, that's not possible.

The whole idea behind OAuth2 is this callback and your default browser will not know how to process the callback data.

It would have to properly receive the URI, parse the data, and then return the data to your application - the thing you should do yourself.

What will happen is that the redirect URI gets called and if your intent filter on your componet matched the component will get started.
 Those callback results you will then have to handle in `onNewIntent` or `onCreate` / `onResume`, depending on your choice architecture.